# What is the name of the design pattern used

Tags: spring, design-patterns, cdi

I am struggling to identify the name of the design pattern I used to bridge between the spring container and CDI container. This is the class I wrote to use the spring beans in my CDI container:

```
   @ApplicationScoped
public class CDIFactory {

ApplicationContext applicationContext = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("classpath:spring/context/application-context.xml");

@Produces
public ServiceManager facadeServices(){
    return (ServiceManager) applicationContext.getBean("ServiceManager");   
}
```

Your help would be appreciated.

Comment: [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_%28object-oriented_programming%29) as the class name suggests? Or [service locator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern)? Or is there something deeper in there?

Comment: ServiceFacade maybe?

Comment: ServiceFacade maybe?

Comment: @PavelHoral I am not sure if it's Factory, that's why I am looking for your suggestions

Comment: @EngineerDollery I don't think so

Comment: Is it creating / providing instance of some class to other components? Then it is a factory... at least from CDI perspective.

Comment: You need to understand patterns first and then answer your own question. Only knowing a 'pattern name' wouldn't help you to better coding or design.

Comment: Patterns have intent (to solve a problem that occurs often). Please explain what problem this code solved for you (bridging between containers isn't very clear to me). If it's a one-time problem, then you don't likely have a pattern.

Comment: @JuanZe thank you for your advice, I'll be working on it. Just to clarify, I didn't answer yet my question. I used CDIFactory name because I thought that Factory DP is the closest to my problem.

Comment: @Fuhrmanator I am developping an application with spring core and jsf2.2.To avoid loosing the benefits of CDI, I didn't use the springResolver to use my spring Beans.Instead, I  made this CDIFactory, so that I can inject my springBeansServices easily in my CDI Beans of the presentation layer

Answer (score 1):

`CDIFactory` is Singleton because it is annotated with `@ApplicationScoped` and `CDIFactory#facadeServices` is Factory Method since it provides `ServiceManager` instance/instances.